# generic term: thieves trap

Tags: vocabulary

If police set up a trap in order to either identify or even catch a thief (e.g. by means of a bait car, or a special invisible  dye  on bank notes), is the general term for such a ploy a "thieves trap"?

Comment: What have you found on the internet?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the term sting operation

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_operation

Comment: According to Jona Lewie, an alternative term is "Police Trap." See https://myspace.com/jonalewieofficial/music/song/police-trap-39832310-42232462